# How to fix and extract google CSE JSON API results with excel vba

Tags: json, excel, vba, web-scraping, google-custom-search

I am newbie over here.
Trying to extract with my VBA code which was given by friend. But he not good at JSON related. I tried searches here on this particular code. Did not find the correct code to.

Here, I am trying to extract only title, url and description of all results.

https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?alt=json&cx=016252715861662448569:taxvfdziuic&num=10&start=1&key=APIKey&q= "sales manager"

```
'Reference for early binding: Microsoft XML v6.0

Public Sub Custom_Search_All()

Dim URLsSheet As Worksheet, resultsSheet As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long, r As Long
Dim result As Variant
Dim lst As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim rownum As Long
rownum = 4
Set URLsSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set resultsSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
resultsSheet.Cells.ClearContents
resultsSheet.Range("A3:D3").Value = Array("Title", "Link", "Summary", "Updated")

With URLsSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For r = 2 To lastRow
        Set lst = Google_CSE1(.Cells(r, "A").Value)
        For i = 0 To lst.Length - 1
            result = GetNodeValues(lst(i))
            resultsSheet.Cells(rownum, "A").Resize(1, UBound(result)).Value = result
            rownum = rownum + 1
        Next
    Next
    ReplaceTags resultsSheet
    resultsSheet.Range("A3").Select
End With
End Sub

Public Function GetNodeValues(node As IXMLDOMNode) As Variant
Dim results(1 To 4) As String
results(1) = node.SelectSingleNode("a:title").Text
results(2) = node.SelectSingleNode("a:link").Attributes.getNamedItem("href").Text
results(3) = Replace(node.SelectSingleNode("a:summary").Text, vbLf, " ") 'remove multiple line chars
results(4) = Cvt_ISO8601DT_Excel(node.SelectSingleNode("a:updated").Text)
GetNodeValues = results
End Function

Public Function Google_CSE1(queryURL As String) As IXMLDOMNodeList

Static XMLdoc As DOMDocument60
Dim lst As IXMLDOMNodeList

'https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list
'
'The cse.list method returns metadata about the search performed, metadata about the custom search engine used for the search, and the search results.
'
'This method requires three query parameters:
'
'   The search engine to use in your request (using the cx query parameter)
'   The search terms for in this request (using the q query parameter).
'   Your API key (using the key query parameter).

If XMLdoc Is Nothing Then Set XMLdoc = New DOMDocument60
With XMLdoc

    'How To Specify Namespace when Querying the DOM with XPath - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/294797

    'Search response starts with the following XML:
    '< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"? >
    '< feed gd:kind="customsearch#search" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:cse="http://schemas.google.com/cseapi/2010"
    'xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" >

    XMLdoc.async = False
    XMLdoc.validateOnParse = False
    XMLdoc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
    XMLdoc.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:a='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'"
    XMLdoc.Load queryURL
End With
Set lst = XMLdoc.SelectNodes("/a:feed/a:entry")
Set Google_CSE1 = lst

End Function

Private Function Cvt_ISO8601DT_Excel(dt As String) As Date

'Convert ISO8601 date time UTC (in the format yyyy-mm-ddthh-mm-ssz) to an Excel date-time
'                                             1234567890123456789
'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC

Cvt_ISO8601DT_Excel = DateSerial(Mid(dt, 1, 4), Mid(dt, 6, 2), Mid(dt, 9, 2)) + TimeSerial(Mid(dt, 12, 2), Mid(dt, 15, 2), Mid(dt, 18, 2))

End Function

Sub ReplaceTags(sht As Worksheet)
sht.Activate
sht.Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.Replace What:="<b>", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="</b>", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="<br>", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="&nbsp;...", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="...", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

@QHarr Your script cannot not handle colon, double quotes and does not skip Urls where there is no data present on specific urls.  It also does not show till which urls it has completed extracting data.

I would appreciate if anyone could help me in this.

Comment: What is summary? Snippet?

Answer (score 1):

It's json so parse as json

You can use that with an [XMLHTTPRequest](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/) to grab the JSON data and then parse the response with a tool such as [JSONConverter](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas). 
After you have added the `.bas` to your project you need to go VBE>Tools>References and add a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`.

In VBA Json `[]` are collections you `For Each` over/access by index; `{}` are dictionaries you access by key.

The below is showing you access paths and how to efficiently store and write out results. I have assumed `summary` is `snippet`. Easy to change this key if required.

TODO: You might want to handle the cases where no items are present; non 200 response http codes etc.

This assumes column A sheet 1 has the search terms in each cell e.g. sales manager android developer and column B has a concatenation of the base url with the url encoded search terms.

Layout:

[image]

Col A with keywords (may need be joined with + in between) and B has the base url string of:

"https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?alt=json&cx=016252715861662448569:taxvfdziuic&num=10&start=1&key=yourAPIkey&q="

onto which you add the url encoded search terms:

```
="https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?alt=json&cx=016252715861662448569:taxvfdziuic&num=10&start=1&key=yourAPIkey&q=" & ENCODEURL(A1)
```

---

VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    ' VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim listings As Object, headers(), urls(), final()
    Dim urlSheet As Worksheet, resultSheet As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Set urlSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set resultSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    headers = Array("Title", "Link", "Summary")
    lastRow = urlSheet.Cells(urlSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Search terms are in column A
    urls = Application.Transpose(urlSheet.Range("B1:B" & lastRow).Value) ' assumes urls start in row 1

    ReDim final(1 To UBound(urls))

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        For i = LBound(urls) To UBound(urls)     'make each request with new url
            .Open "GET", urls(i), False
            .send
            Set listings = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)("items")

            Dim results, listing As Object, r As Long, c As Long
            ReDim results(1 To listings.Count, 1 To 3)
            r = 0
            For Each listing In listings
                r = r + 1
                results(r, 1) = listing("title")
                results(r, 2) = listing("link")
                results(r, 3) = listing("snippet")
            Next
            final(i) = results                   'store current results in final array
        Next
    End With
    Dim arr()
    With resultSheet
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        For i = LBound(final) To UBound(final)
            arr = final(i)
            .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1).Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192487/discussion-on-answer-by-qharr-how-to-fix-and-extract-google-cse-json-api-results).

Comment: Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: It runs perfectly for your example. If you feel it needs "fixing" you are going to have to update your question with why it needs fixing and give failing case. As is, I think my answer solves your problem as stated.